# RabbitMQ - what to do if client is unable to handle the message

Tags: rabbitmq

I am wondering what would be the best practice when a consumer is not able to handle the message it receives. What would be the mechanism to notify the rabbit to it will either put it back on to the queue or move to an error queue?

im using the .net client from rabbitmq

Answer (score 2):

Either discard it or put it on an error queue.  If there is a problem with the message such that the consumer cannot handle it then do not put it back on the queue as the consumer will just try to read it again.
It is an exception so handle it as such. In the exception handling you should raise an error message stating what happened and what you have done with the message.  Best practice is to put it on an error queue where it could be handled manually.